# Hi to everyone, I'm stuck with this problem in SQL: mysql gives me always syntax error at line 4 but I don't really know what it may be

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Here it's the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER inserisci_richiesta_noID AFTER INSERT ON Richiesta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    IF (NEW.ID_Cliente == NULL AND (NEW.Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM Utente))) THEN
        INSERT INTO Utente(ID, Nome, Cognome, Email, Telefono, ID_Livello_accesso)
        VALUES (NULL, 'Generato', 'Automaticamnete', NEW.Email, NEW.Telefono, 1);
        UPDATE Richiesta
        SET ID_Cliente = (SELECT ID FROM Cliente WHERE Email = :NEW.Email);
    ELSE NEW.ID_Cliente == NULL AND NEW.Email IN (SELECT Email FROM Utente;) THEN
        UPDATE Richiesta
        SET ID_Cliente = (SELECT ID FROM Cliente WHERE Email = NEW.Email);
    END IF;
END;
```

it gives me this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '== NULL AND (NEW.Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM Utente))) THEN
>           INSERT INTO U' at line 4

Comment: sorry for the awful syntax but it's my first question here :)

Comment: have you tried replacing '== NULL' by 'is NULL' ?

Comment: ELSE -> ELSE IF

Comment: MySQL have no `==` operator. To compare with NULL value you must use `IS NULL` operator or null-safe compare operator `<=>`.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick anserws, I've tried but it gives me alway an error, now I post the new code

Answer (score 0):

This is the code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER inserisci_richiesta_noID AFTER INSERT ON Richiesta
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
 IF (NEW.ID_Cliente IS NULL AND (NEW.Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM Utente))) THEN
    INSERT INTO Utente(ID, Nome, Cognome, Email, Telefono, ID_Livello_accesso)
    VALUES (NULL, 'Generato', 'Automaticamnete', NEW.Email, NEW.Telefono, 1)
    UPDATE Richiesta
    SET ID_Cliente = (SELECT ID FROM Cliente WHERE Email = NEW.Email);
ELSE IF (NEW.ID_Cliente IS NULL AND NEW.Email IN (SELECT Email FROM Utente)) THEN
    UPDATE Richiesta
    SET ID_Cliente = (SELECT ID FROM Cliente WHERE Email = NEW.Email);
END IF;
END$$

 DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: You need a terminator after the insert and else if should be elseif but biggest(maybe) problem is you cannot action Richiesta in the trigger.- you can set the NEW. values in a before trigger..